# What Language To Use To Manipulate OSX Application Windows?

Tags: python, macos

I'm sure many of us have seen vision degradation from too much screen time from programming.

A theory suggests that when they eyes become fixed, tension builds.  And that tension causes the vision to slowly degrade.

This software promises to prevent that fixation...

http://www.central-fixation.com/downloads.php

The problem is it's outdated, and Windows only.

I'd like to write a script that will "swing" all open windows according to a set pattern & speed.  A script that works with OSX 10.9 and later.

I know Python and Javascript but have no idea where to start on this.

Please help me out.

How is it done?  What language is used to manipulate OSX application windows?  And/or simply manipulate the whole desktop window space?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to do exactly what you are trying to achieve here, but ANYTHING at all related to manipulating OS X should be done via Automator or AppleScript. If you are running Yosemite, the app is called "Script Editor". Anything older and it's called "AppleScript Editor".

Try [this](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/firsttutorial/10.html) site.

Extract:

```
tell application "Finder" to set the position of the front Finder window to {94, 134}
```

I know your question is labeled "python" but I believe that AppleScript is the way to go with this.

You can add AppleScript to an Automator workflow with the "script" object. I'm not sure how to make this run periodically, but one option would be to keep it open in the background. You can do this in AppleScript with the `delay` command:

```
(do stuff here)
delay (your delay)
```

Hope this achieves your purpose.